# convert listbox items to array integers C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, arraylist, int

Having trouble adding integers to the item array of a list box. Cannot seem to convert the listbox to integer.

```
int[] ratingArray = new int[numberRatingsInt];
for (int i = 0; i < numberRatingsInt; i++)
{
    ratingArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ratingListBox.Items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.ToString()` to `ratingListBox.Items[i]`

It should be:

```
int[] ratingArray = new int[numberRatingsInt];
for (int i = 0; i < ratingListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ratingArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ratingListBox.Items[i].ToString());
}
```

**Just Tested:**

`.value` after `ratingListBox.Items[i]` can also work.

It can also work like following:

```
int[] ratingArray = new int[numberRatingsInt];
for (int i = 0; i < ratingListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ratingArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ratingListBox.Items[i].Value);
}
```

(This was tested added in reference to @Chris answer.)

**Edit:**

put `ratingListBox.Items.Count` in for loop condition.

Comment: Thanks, i think this has fixed it. However i now have another error "ArgumentOutOfRangeException was handled by user code" not sure what this has to do with now..

Comment: Its related to index. Your index in array is going wrong somewhere. For loop index is going somewhere wrong. Can you put debugger on this code?

Comment: @AnthonyJohnson `ratingListBox.Items` does not contain `numberRatingsInt` elements, hence the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: @AnthonyJohnson go through edit "ratingListBox.Items.Count" in for loop

Comment: @AnthonyJohnson Always Welcome.

Answer (score 2):

`ListBoxes` contain `ListItems`, not the value directly. Try this:

```
 int[] ratingArray = new int[numberRatingsInt];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberRatingsInt; i++)
    {
        ratingArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ratingListBox.Items[i].Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the other answers, you can also do a sexy lambda something like:

```
int[] ratingArray = ratingListBox.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
                                 .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value))
                                 .ToArray();
```

This should get rid of all the loops counts, consts etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
var modarray = ratingListBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToArray();
int[] arr = modarray.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```